# Can i use free font under OFL license for android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, fonts, copyright-display

I wish you all the best.
I want to use a Free font under OFL license for my app.

Is this going to cause property rights problem for me in the future?

Also, should i make a property rights notice for the font inside the app or in it's description or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any license, you must adhere to the terms and condition specified within the license. The [OFL](https://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=OFL_web) has a section entitled "PERMISSION & CONDITIONS", so do what it says there and you should be OK. I assume that the font you will be using is available under the OFL license and the owners state as much.

As for the notice, the license I reference above states:

> 2. Original or Modified Versions of the Font Software may be bundled,
>    redistributed and/or sold with any software, provided that each copy
>    contains the above copyright notice and this license. These can be
>    included either as stand-alone text files, human-readable headers or
>    in the appropriate machine-readable metadata fields within text or
>    binary files as long as those fields can be easily viewed by the user.

Do that and you should be OK as far as notice goes, but look at the license provided by the owners of the font you wish you use and make sure you know what else it might say.

(This is not legal advice but my understanding about how these things work.)